# How to use a field on a foreign key (another model) as part of my model primary key value

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-admin

I'm new to Django and I feel sometimes it is not clear in which .py of myApp I should write solutions and examples I see.

In my models.py I have a model called Project and a model called Order. In admin section (http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/myApp/), I would like the user to type a project number when creating a new project. Every project can have multiple Orders. I would like the Order primary key to be composed of the Project number it belongs to, plus a consecutive number. The user can only change the consecutive number part of the Oder primary key but not alter the Project number the order belongs to.

For instance for Project with project_number(primary key) = 951, Orders primary keys can be 951-1, 951-2, etc

Another project with project_number(primary key) = 1015 can also have orders 1,2, etc but they won't conflict with orders of project 951 because they will be labelled 1015-1, 1015-2, etc.

1. Is it possible to achieve this in models.py?
2. How would I have to modify order_number field below?

Notice I need the order_number field to fetch its project_number from order_project field and I won't know the order_project exact value until the user is creating the order and associating it with a project.

If what I'm asking can't be done please suggest a way to solve this and clearly explain in which .py of myApp I should write the code.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True,primary_key=True)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=400)

class Order(models.Model): 
    order_project = models.ForeignKey("Project", on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name = "Project to which this order is associated",related_name= "orders_for_project")
    order_number = models.CharField(unique=True,primary_key=True,max_length = 10)
```

UPDATE:

Following suggestions from the community my code now looks like this:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True,primary_key=True)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=400)

class Order(models.Model): 
    order_project = models.ForeignKey("Project", on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name = "Project to which this order is associated",related_name= "orders_for_project")
    order_number = models.IntegerField(default=1,validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    class Meta:
        #TODO capture error and present it in human readable form 
        constraints = [ models.UniqueConstraint(fields= ['order_project','order_number'], name = 'unique_order_id'),]

    def __str__(self):
    return str(self.order_project.project_number) + ("-") + str(self.order_number) + (" : ") + str(self.order_description)
```

I do not fully understand why my Order primary key could not be formed considering the value of the primary key of Project but this is a workaround solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep Order's primary key independent from Product's PK, just set uniqueness constraint on `order_project_id` + `order_number` combination:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_project = models.ForeignKey("Project", on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name = "Project to which this order is associated",related_name= "orders_for_project")
    order_number = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('order_project', 'order_number')
```

Then if you want to display order number in `{order_project_id}-{order_number}` format you can just generate this value using those 2 fields in runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please notice I don't need to create the order position field. That is the order number which is at the same time part of the primary key. I need to be able to incorporate order_project in order_number primary key value. If I define order_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True,primary_key=True), I still can't create 2 orders with id = 1 for different projects. It gives me this error: Order with this Order number already exists.

Comment: That's correct, this is why you shouldn't set `unique=True` on `order_number`. There is a `unique_together` property that you should use. Please read my answer more carefully. I'll update it to use `oprder_number` instead of `oder_position` though

Comment: I did include the unique together property but was also keeping the primary key in true. So unique together combination is now my primary key? How can I display {order_project_id}-{order_position} in my admin section?

Comment: You should use UniqueConstraint instead of unique_together which will be deprecated. Otherwise, GProst is right. And simply create a method on the Order object that display what you want. It can even be your __str__(self)

Comment: Why Order's primary key must be kept independent from Product's PK?

Comment: You could in theory make Order's PK equal to Project's PK + number part by setting it like this manually in the `pre_save` signal for example.
But it is a worse approach because it won't provide you a guarantee that your Order's PK will always be aligned with Project's PK. For example, what if you decide to change Project's ID? Or assign an Order to another Project? You'd need to make sure you change Order's ID as well. I know that it's probably not something that you'd do but the point is I don't see a reason why you'd want to implement a less flexible solution for your goal.